# Dealing with uncaught exceptions in Java EE 7 Server API relying on CORS

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, exception, cors

I have a server written in Java EE 7 running on Wildfly 8.1.0.Final. The server will be used by several different JavaScript clients hosted on different domains. For this reason, I need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing by setting the proper HTTP headers on each response. These headers are added with a simple `ContainerResponseFilter`:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       final ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, X-Token, X-User-Name");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");

        // ...
    }
}
```

This works well for all "normal" requests. However, whenever an uncaught exception is thrown on the server, the HTTP 5XX response seems to simply skip the filters. This means that all JavaScript clients hosted on different domains form the server (which in my case means every single one) are unable to parse the response at all. Instead, they just see the standard error CORS-related error message in the JavaScript console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load <server URL>. Origin <JavaScript client URL> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I know there are ways of intercepting every single exception in the application and catch it at some high level, but I am worried about the performance impact this will have on my server. It is also important that the solution is JEE7 spec compliant, so doing anything specific to JBoss/Wildfly is unfortunately not an option.

How can I best handle this problem?

**EDIT**: I realise I could let a web server like nginx reverse proxy to Wildfly, and let *nginx* set the CORS-related HTTP headers on the response. However, I would very much like to be able to just deploy the application to any application server without the additional hassle of configuring a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to register an `ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>` to handle the normal responses.

Then register an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` to catch all other, add your CORS headers and map the appropriate response.

Here's some examples http://avianey.blogspot.com/2011/12/exception-mapping-jersey.html

Comment: I had no idea ExceptionMappers were even a thing. Thank you so much!

A small note: "catching" the exception with an ExceptionMapper actually allows the response to pass through the ResponseFilter chain, so there was no need to add the new headers in the mapper -- the filter did that for me.